# String[] from ArrayList<Class>

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

I recently started working on an app that does a request to a server and gets a json response.

The "thing" functioned beautifully until i had to implement new stuff in the list and now i have a hard time to fix it.

Any help is very appreciated:

```
class RemoteConfig
{

// names and type must match what we get from the remote
String[] username;

ArrayList<accDetails> in_groups;

String[] in_groups_sorted;

class accDetails
{
  int group_id;
  String group_label;
  Boolean _is_system;
}
```

This is just a part of how the class starts, and here is how the json reponse looks like:

```
{  
"username":[  
    "mike"
],
"in_groups":[  
    {  
        "group_id":2,
        "group_label":"All users",
        "_is_system":true
    },
    {  
        "group_id":4372,
        "group_label":"Privileged User",
        "_is_system":false
    },
    {  
        "group_id":4979,
        "group_label":"Supervisor",
        "_is_system":false
    }
]
}
```

The problem that i encounter now, is that i have no idea on how to split the in_groups array list and get into String[] in_groups_sorted the value of Group_label if the _is_system value is false.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you,
Mike

---

After checking the responses, the cleanest and simplest was the one provided by Abbe:

```
public String[] groupSettings()
{
    String[] levels = new String[] {};

    if (remoteConfig != null && remoteConfig.in_groups != null){
        for (accDetails ad: remoteConfig.in_groups)
        {
            if (!ad._is_system) {
                levels = ArrayUtils.addAll(levels, ad.group_label); ;
            }
        }
    }

    return levels;
}
```

Comment: You parse the json (using JsonObject/JsonArray and so on) or you let the API build the Object for you?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. I was going to far with my thinking and i forgot to keep it simple. I used part of the code that @Abbe Resina offered and it worked properly. The others were successful as well, but this was the simplest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I suppose the JSON is already parsed and stored in the `in_groups` field of `RemoteConfig` class. And you just need to filter the information you need to populate the `in_group_sorted` field.

Add the following to the `RemoteConfig` class:

```
public initGroupSorted() {
   // Temporary list, since we don't know the size once filtered 
   List<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();
   for (accDetails ad : in_groups) {
      if (ad._is_system) {
        groups.add(ad.group_label);
      }
   }
   in_group_sorted = labels.toArray(new String[labels.size()]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I modified it for my needs and now it works :) Simple and clean

Answer (score 1):

if you don´t want to change the way you parse your JSON, you could always do this:

Let accDetails implement Comparable and then use Collections.sort passing in_groups.

if you really want the String[] you could always iterate over in_groups, add to in_groups_sorted and then using Arrays.sort

Answer (score 0):

Mike, let me give you something that should get you going. From your question i got the feeling that your problem was on how to parse the JSON, so before you go write your own parser, consider the following piece of code that i just wrote:

```
public void createObjects(String rawJSON) {
        try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(rawJSON);
            JSONArray username = object.getJSONArray("username");
            JSONArray inGroups = object.getJSONArray("in_groups");

            RemoteConfig config = new RemoteConfig();
            config.in_groups = new ArrayList<>();
            config.username = username.getString(0);

            for (int i = 0; i < inGroups.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject group = inGroups.getJSONObject(i);
                if (!group.getBoolean("_is_system")) {
                    accDetails details = new accDetails();
                    details.group_id = group.getInt("group_id");
                    details.group_label = group.getString("group_label");
                    details._is_system = false;
                   config.in_groups.add(details);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you. I wil test now and let you know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Java 8 Solution using [Stream's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) `filter`,`sorted`, and `map` methods:

```
//ArrayList<accDetails> in_groups is already populated
Stream<accDetails> tempStream= in_groups.stream().filter(p -> p._is_system == false);
tempStream= tempStream.sorted((accDetails o1, accDetails o2) -> o1.group_label.compareTo(o2.group_label));
String[] in_groups_sorted = tempStream.map(s -> s.group_label).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Separated the calls for visibility, but they can be a one liner:

```
String[] in_groups_sorted = in_groups.stream().filter(p -> p._is_system == false).sorted((accDetails o1, accDetails o2) -> o1.group_label.compareTo(o2.group_label)).map(s -> s.group_label).toArray(String[]::new);
```